# Getting the following exception after changing the index name

Tags: elasticsearch

I have changed the index name from "sample1" to "sample2", but after making that I am getting the exception while indexing a record in elastic-search:

```
org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlockException: blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/4/index closed];
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlocks.indexBlockedException(ClusterBlocks.java:158)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.checkRequestBlock(TransportIndexAction.java:174)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.checkRequestBlock(TransportIndexAction.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.start(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:353)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.start(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:330)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.doExecute(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:101)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.innerExecute(TransportIndexAction.java:134)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.doExecute(TransportIndexAction.java:116)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.doExecute(TransportIndexAction.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:63)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$OperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$OperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:185)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleRequest(MessageChannelHandler.java:212)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:109)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

**How should I go about it**?

Comment: Your index is closed, you need to open it: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-open-close.html

Comment: How did you rename you index? To my knowledge there is no real way to rename an index. Problem is that all documents ids need to be changed since the name of the index is part of the id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thing, your Index is closed, Execute below command for change the close status to open status.
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/_open'

You can follow below link for Aliases
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html .